# Firebase invalid-api-key when deploying with Github Actions/Firebase hosting

Tags: typescript, firebase, vue.js, github, vite

I'm currently trying to make my Vue3/Vite4 app a bit more secure. To this extent, I tried to hide my API key in a .env file for dev, and in my Github repo secrets for prod (this is the only way I've found to both give Firebase my API key AND not having to push it on my repo).

But even if the Github workflow (generated by firebase CLI) succeeds, I cannot get my website's content because of an "Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key)".

I don't understand because I tried to print my secret variable on the workflow run, and it does give me the right API key :

```js
const apikey = process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY;
console.log(`Api key on prod is : ${apikey}`);
```

...prints :

[image]

with the right api key (not showing it obv).

Here is my workflow yaml :

```
# This file was auto-generated by the Firebase CLI
# https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge
'on':
  push:
    branches:
      - main

env:
  FIREBASE_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_API_KEY }}

jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: npm ci && npm run build
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_DATABATTLE_BOGA }}'
          channelId: live
          projectId: databattle-boga
```

And here is my firebase config (works totally fine in dev) :

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'

export const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
    apiKey: import.meta?.env?.VITE_FIREBASE_API_KEY ? import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_API_KEY : process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: "databattle-boga.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "databattle-boga",
    storageBucket: "databattle-boga.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "656991003457",
    appId: "1:656991003457:web:3b377396a4bb8680cf77c0",
    measurementId: "G-PP2V9JHQQT"  
});
```

Of course, if you have a better way to do this (easier or more secure), don't hesitate to tell me. I'm quite struggling on the security problems of my webapps.
Thanks in advance!